# Variational inequality and saddle point problem

Tags: convex-optimization

I refer to the following paper: (fix the wrong link)
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5723-adaptive-primal-dual-splitting-methods-for-statistical-learning-and-image-processing.pdf

In that paper, we consider the saddle point problem:
$$ \min_x \max_y f(x)+y^TAx - g(y) $$

Then, this paper says that variational inequality formulation is that
$$ h(u) - h(u^*) + (u-u^*)^TQ(u^*)\geq 0, \quad\forall u\in\Omega \tag{18} $$

where $h(u) = f(x)+g(y)$ and $u=(x,y)$.

However, I am very confused after reading following material in 62page.

http://meeting.xidian.edu.cn/workshop/miis2012/uploads/files/20120409/20120409170826.pdf

[image]

I don't know why $h(u)$, instead of $\nabla h(u)$, appears in (18). Is there anyone who help me?

---

(added)
What I understood is that the solution $x^*$ of the following problem for a convex set $K$,
$$ \min_x f(x) \quad \text{s.t. } x\in K $$
satisfy the following:
$$ (y-x^*)^T\nabla f(x^*)\geq 0,\quad \forall y\in K $$

So I wonder why $(u-u^*)\nabla h(u^*)$ doesn't appear in (18).

Comment: Are you sure about the first link ? The paper doesn't even mention the word "variational" ...

Comment: I am sorry to write incorrect link. I have fixed the link. Thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: The **necessary** inequality (18) has derivatives "hidden" in it. Indeed, the first-order optimality conditions $ Ax^* \in \partial g(y^*)$ and $-A^Ty^* \in \partial f(x^*),$ for $u^* := (x^*, y^*)$ to be a saddle-point, are equivalent to inequalities (16) and (17) respectively.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain in more detail about "hidden" derivatives?

Comment: The inequality (18)  involving no derivatives was arrived at by subtracting the first-order inequalities (16) and (17), which involve derivatives (in fact, subdifferentials). Why would you expect $\nabla h$ to appear in (18) ? Maybe I'm missing something in your question ?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've added my question in response to your comment.